# Is there a way to get a fade in effect from hidden visibility (CSS, JS)?

Tags: javascript, html, css

In my webpage, I used CSS to set `opacity=0` and `transition:opacity linear 0.5s` in the body, then used JS to set `opacity=1` when the page loads. However, there is a `<div>` that I want to remain invisible, so I used CSS to set `visibility="hidden"`. If I used opacity, my `<div>` would appear with the rest of the page.

Is there either
1. A way to set the body's opacity to 1, but not a `<div>` element inside it (I considered applying opacity to sections around it but I would like the entire page to appear at once)?
2. A way to fade in the  text other than opacity (I tried the fadeIn() from jQuery, but I don't think it worked when my visibility was still hidden)?

Comment: Its unrelated to your question, but you can use animate css library here https://daneden.github.io/animate.css/

Answer (score 0):

Apply the `visibility:visible` for the div:

```css
#main{
  visibility: hidden;
}
#child{
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">main is not visible
  <div id="child">child still visible</div>
</div>
```

Do opposite if you want child to be invisible and main visible. (But I don't think this is what you want.)

```
#main{visibility:visible;}#child{visibility:hidden;}
```

`#main` visibility is not necessary if this is the case.

Answer (score 0):

The div with opacity set to 0 should still remain **invisible**, even though the body is now visible.

Refer to my example here: 
http://codepen.io/partypete25/pen/rePXag

**CSS**

```
body {
  opacity:0;
  background:red;  
  transition:opacity linear 2s;
}

div {
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  background:blue;
  opacity:0;
}
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
var x = document.getElementsByTagName("BODY")[0];
x.style.opacity = "1";
```